# pthread and conditional variables

Tags: concurrency, pthreads, condition-variable

I am following the tutorial on pthread from [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t condition_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
#define COUNT_HALT1  3
#define COUNT_HALT2  6

main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   exit(0);
}

void *functionCount1()
{
   for(;;)
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock( &condition_mutex );
      while( count >= COUNT_HALT1 && count <= COUNT_HALT2 )
      {
         pthread_cond_wait( &condition_cond, &condition_mutex );
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &condition_mutex );

      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
      count++;
      printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n",count);
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }
}

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &condition_mutex );
       if( count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2 )
       {
          pthread_cond_signal( &condition_cond );
       }
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &condition_mutex );

       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
       count++;
       printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n",count);
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

       if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }

}
```

And the author adds  that `functioncount1()` is halted for values between the values `COUNT_HALT1` and `COUNT_HALT2`.

A sample output is as follows:

```
Counter value functionCount1: 1
Counter value functionCount1: 2
Counter value functionCount1: 3
Counter value functionCount2: 4
Counter value functionCount2: 5
Counter value functionCount2: 6
Counter value functionCount2: 7
Counter value functionCount1: 8
Counter value functionCount1: 9
Counter value functionCount1: 10
Counter value functionCount2: 11
```

From my observation of the code, shouldn't 3 be counted by `functionCount2`? In the while loop in `functionCount1`, it calls `wait()` on any value **including** 3, which leads me to think that 3 should be counted by `functionCount2`, instead of `functionCount1`.

Why isn't it so?

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to an object from multiple threads.

Comment: @EOF but there are mutex to ensure we're synchronizing for values between 3 to 6.  The author even mentions that "The only thing that has been ensures is that functionCount2 will increment the count between the values COUNT_HALT1 and COUNT_HALT2. Everything else is random."

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races 4 Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the
other one reads or modifies the same memory location. 25 The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in
different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the
other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.* Undefined. Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

One thread may read `count` with only the `condition_mutex` held (where `count` is tested against `COUNT_HALT1` and `COUNT_HALT`)  or with no mutex held at all (where `count` is tested against `COUNT_DONE`) while the other thread can modify `count` with only the `count_mutex` held.  This unsynchronised access results in undefined behaviour, as @EOF noted in comments to the question, so the code is simply incorrect.

That said, even if we ran only `functionCount1()` without the other thread (so that the unsynchronised access does not occur), we would still expect to see this output:

```
Counter value functionCount1: 1
Counter value functionCount1: 2
Counter value functionCount1: 3
```

That's because the counter value is printed *after* the increment, so in the last iteration it sees an initial counter value of 2, does not wait, increments the counter, then prints the new counter value of 3.

Note that in your original code, even ignoring the unsynchronised access, there *is* still a possibility for `functionCount1` to perform the increment from 3 to 4.  This is because in between `functionCount1` seeing a `count` value of 2 and deciding not to wait, and actually locking the `count_mutex`, the value could be incremented by the other thread.

To remove both the unsynchronised access to `count` and fix the race referred to the in previous paragraph, you simply remove `condition_mutex` entirely and use `count_mutex` instead, keeping it locked between the `pthread_cond_wait()` return and the actual increment of `count`.  This is the general pattern: the mutex you have locked when you call `pthread_cond_wait()` should be the mutex protecting the shared state that you are waiting for with your condition variable (here, that shared state is just the `count` variable):

```
void *functionCount1()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        while( count >= COUNT_HALT1 && count <= COUNT_HALT2 )
        {   
            pthread_cond_wait( &condition_cond, &count_mutex );
        }

        count++;
        printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n",count);

        if (count >= COUNT_DONE)
        {   
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
            return(NULL);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
    }
}

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        if( count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2 )
        {
            pthread_cond_signal( &condition_cond );
        }

        count++;
        printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n",count);

        if (count >= COUNT_DONE)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
            return(NULL);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
    }
}
```

This is not optimal, however: the mutex is kept locked for longer than necessary.  If you don't care about arbitrary output interleaving between the threads, then you don't need to have `count_mutex` locked while you call `printf()`, as long as you take a local copy of the new `count` value to pass to `printf()`.  You can also use that local copy in the exit test as well.

Furthermore, the signalling condition only needs to be tested *after* `functionCount2()` has changed `count`.  `pthread_mutex_signal()` doesn't have to be called with the mutex held, so we can put that after the `printf()` as well, using the local copy of the count:

```
void *functionCount1()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        int my_count;

        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        while( count >= COUNT_HALT1 && count <= COUNT_HALT2 )
        {
            pthread_cond_wait( &condition_cond, &count_mutex );
        }

        count++;
        my_count = count;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

        printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n", my_count);

        if (my_count >= COUNT_DONE)
            return(NULL);
    }
}

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        int my_count;

        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        count++;
        my_count = count;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

        printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n", my_count);

        if ( my_count < COUNT_HALT1 || my_count > COUNT_HALT2 )
        {
            pthread_cond_signal( &condition_cond );
        }

        if (my_count >= COUNT_DONE)
            return(NULL);
    }
}
```

As noted above, you probably won't see the `printf()` output ordered in strict count order anymore, because we're no longer forcing the printf() to happen atomically with the increment.